# What is wrong in this inner product proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

This proposition is stated in my linear algebra notes:

> (Let $V$ be a inner product space) for any $x,y,z \in V$, if $〈x,y〉 = 〈x,z〉$ for any $x \in V$, then $y = z$. (#)

Now I try to apply this proposition to the following:

> Let $T$ be a linear operator on a (finite-dimensional) inner product space $V$ over the field of real numbers.
> Denote $T^*$ to be the adjoint of $T$, we know by definition that for any $x, y \in V$, $〈T(x),y〉 = 〈x,T^*(y)〉$.
> Since we are working on a real inner product space, we can switch the order of the inner products directly without adding a conjugation. 
> Now for any $x \in V$, $〈T(x),x〉 = 〈x,T^*(x)〉= 〈T^*(x),x〉$.
> This implies $〈x,T(x)〉=〈x,T^*(x)〉$ for any $x \in V$.
> Then using (#), I can say $T(x) = T^*(x)$ for any $x \in V$.
> This further implies $T = T^*$, or $T$ is self-adjoint.

which is strange. Does this mean every linear operator on a real inner product space is self-adjoint?
Can anyone tell me where is the flaw in my "proof"? Thanks.

Comment: In the statement *"if $〈x,y〉 = 〈x,z〉$ for any $x \in V$, then $y = z$"*, note that $y$ and $z$ do not depend on $x$.

Comment: What you've actually shown is that $\langle x,(T-T^\ast) x \rangle = 0$ for all $x \in V$. Note that the operator $T-T^\ast$ is skew-adjoint in the sense that $(T-T^\ast)^\ast = -(T-T^\ast)$. For comparison, let $A$ be an $n \times n$ real matrix that is skew-symmetric in the sense that $A^T= -A$. What do you then know about the diagonal entries of $A$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you have met the requirements of proposition (#).

(#) does provide a test of whether or not $T(x) = T^*(x)$ is true, for a fixed $x$.

You would further need to show $〈a,T(x)〉=〈a,T^*(x)〉$ for all $a$ in the space.

Comment: Possibly you confused youself by reusing the symbol $x$. When I apply a lemma like this, I try to write new symbols for "inside" the lemma, different from the "outside the lemma" symbols